# Why the true value test comes back positive in both cases?

Tags: bash

Here is my script `simple.sh`

```
function b() {
    local a;
    a=$1

        [[ "$a" =~ ^yes* ]]
}


function main(){
    local test;
    test=$(b $1)
        if [[ ${test} ]]; then
        echo Positive I am all good
        fi
        echo The end
}

main $@
```

I expect if I run `bash simple.sh yes` then it will print

```
Positive I am all good
The end
```

but if I run `bash simple.sh no`, it should print

```
The end
```

However when I ran the script in a shell, both print

```
The end
```

Why?

I am using ubuntu xenial.

If I add `-x` flag, I see these traces:

```
$ bash -x simple.sh yes
+ main yes
+ local test
++ b yes
++ local a
++ a=yes
++ [[ yes =~ ^yes* ]]
+ test=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ echo The end
The end

$ bash -x simple.sh no
+ main no
+ local test
++ b no
++ local a
++ a=no
++ [[ no =~ ^yes* ]]
+ test=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ echo The end
The end
```

`test` is blank for some reason

And `bash` version is

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: You forgot a `$` in `[[ test ]]`, it should be `[[ $test ]]`. The string `test` always evaluates to true.

Comment: Thanks! But now the `Positive I am all good` is never printed. I am going to update the question

Comment: `test` is blank because `$( )`, as in `test=$(b $1)`, captures standard output.  Function `b` does not write to `stdout` (maybe using `echo`) so nothing is captured.  What do you expect to be in `test`?

Comment: @cdarke  So would removal of `$()` work? What to replace `$()`?

Comment: Did you mean ` if b $1; then ...` perhaps, rather than using `test`?

Comment: cool. will `if [[ b $1 ]]; then` work and a good style?

Comment: @AnthonyKong: Doing `b "$1"` as in my answer would suffice

Comment: The `[[` is poor style, and misunderstands what `[[` are used for - they are for pattern matching.  The syntax of `if` is `if` *command*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following line:

```sh
test=$(b $1)
```

you are storing the standard output of your function `b` in the variable `test` but your function `b` has no output, it simply has a *return value*, which is not stored. The `test` variable will then always be empty.

To use the return value of your function, you should either use `$?` to be stored in `test`, you have two options:

- **call the function in the `if`**

```sh
function b() {
    local a;
    a="$1"

    [[ "$a" =~ ^yes* ]]
}


function main(){
    if  b "$1"; then            # The if will evaluate the return value (0 means true)
        echo "Positive I am all good"
    fi
    echo The end
}

main $@
```

- **store the return value and evaluate in the `if`**

```sh
function b() {
    local a;
    a="$1"

    [[ "$a" =~ ^yes* ]]
}


function main(){
    local test;
    b $1
    test="$?"
    if [ "${test}" -eq 0 ]; then    # You need to manually evaluate for 0
        echo "Positive I am all good"
    fi
    echo "The end"
}

main $@
```

Comment: The syntax for a function is `function main` *or* `main()`, although that shown will work, it is not strictly correct.  POSIX only requires `main()`.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo().

Comment: Minor semantic note: functions don't have return values, they have *exit statuses* like any other process. The distinction is important, since the exit status is limited in what it can be (basically, a single unsigned byte) compared to the wider array of values that a return value might imply.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the if function method that many people have suggested above, however you can also echo a return value if you wanted to keep the main function the same as what you had before:

```
function b() {
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^yes* ]]; then
     echo "success"
    fi
}


function main(){
    local test;
    test=$(b $1)
    if [[ ${test} ]]; then
      echo Positive I am all good
    fi
    echo The end
}

main $@in $@
```